# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (trying to write snake)

Tags: python

Started learning python and have some issues i cannot solve.

This error does not occur everytime - sometimes when starting program it can happen dozen times and after that it works perfectly fine.

Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snake.py", line 124, in <module>
    pg.draw.rect(win, red, [apple1[0], apple1[1], s
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Actual code:

```
    import pygame as pg
import pygame.freetype
import time
import random

pg.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)

win_h = 600
win_w = 600

win = pg.display.set_mode((win_h, win_w))
pg.display.set_caption('SNEK!')
font_size = 40
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("bauhaus93", font_size)

snake_size = 20
apple_is = False
dir = ''
score = 0
# board size must be divisible by snake_size*2
board_size = (240, 320)
# top, right, bottom, left (must be divisible by snake_size)
board_margin = (40, 20, 20, 80)
board_border_width = 4
bdw = board_border_width

# Snake start point
x1 = board_margin[3] + board_size[0] / 2 - snake_size
y1 = board_margin[0] + board_size[1] / 2 - snake_size
dx = 0
dy = 0
snake_list = [[x1, y1]]

clock = pg.time.Clock()
speed = 10

run = True
start = False
pause = False

def random_apple(j):
    seed = time.time()
    seed = str(seed)
    apple = []
    random.seed(seed[14:len(seed)])
    a = random.randrange(board_margin[3] / snake_size, board_size[0] / snake_size, 1)*snake_size
    random.seed(seed[13:len(seed)-1])
    b = random.randrange(board_margin[0] / snake_size, board_size[1] / snake_size, 1)*snake_size
    for x, v in enumerate(j):
        if a != v[0] and b != v[1]:
            apple.clear()
            apple.append([a, b])
            return apple[0]
        else:
            apple.clear()
            random_apple(j)
    
apple1 = random_apple(snake_list)
    
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT and dir != 'RIGHT':
                dx = -snake_size
                dy = 0
                dir = 'LEFT'
            elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT and dir != 'LEFT':
                dx = snake_size
                dy = 0
                dir = 'RIGHT'
            elif event.key == pg.K_UP and dir != 'DOWN':
                dx = 0
                dy = -snake_size
                dir = 'UP'
            elif event.key == pg.K_DOWN and dir != 'UP':
                dx = 0
                dy = snake_size
                dir = 'DOWN'
            elif event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            elif event.key == pg.K_p:
                if pause:
                    pause = False
                else:
                    pause = True
            start = True
    # Collision detection with borders      
    if x1 >= board_size[0] + board_margin[3] or x1 < board_margin[3] or y1 < board_margin[0] or y1 >= board_size[1] + board_margin[0]:
        run = False
    # Collision detection with snake itself 
    if len(snake_list) > 2:
        for x, v in enumerate(snake_list):
            if x > 1 and v == snake_list[0]:
                run  = False
                
    win.fill(black)
    # Draw board borders [top, right, bottom, left]
    pg.draw.line(win, white, [board_margin[3] - bdw, board_margin[0] - bdw + 1], [board_size[0] + board_margin[3] + bdw/2, board_margin[0] - bdw + 1], bdw)
    pg.draw.line(win, white, [board_size[0] + board_margin[3] + bdw/2 - 1, board_margin[0] - bdw], [board_size[0] + board_margin[3] + bdw/2 - 1, board_size[1] + board_margin[0] + bdw/2], bdw)
    pg.draw.line(win, white, [board_margin[3] - bdw, board_size[1] + board_margin[0] + bdw/2 - 1], [board_size[0] + board_margin[3] + bdw/2, board_size[1] + board_margin[0] + bdw/2 - 1], bdw)
    pg.draw.line(win, white, [board_margin[3] - bdw + 1, board_margin[0] - bdw], [board_margin[3] - bdw + 1, board_size[1] + board_margin[0] + bdw/2], bdw)
    # Generate apple coordinates
    if apple_is == False:
            apple1 = random_apple(snake_list)
            apple_is = True
    # Moving the snake head
    if run and not pause:
        x1 += dx
        y1 += dy
    # Store snake coordinates
    if start and not pause:
        snake_list.insert(0, [x1, y1])
        if len(snake_list) > 1:
            snake_list.pop()
    # Draw apple    
    pg.draw.rect(win, red, [apple1[0], apple1[1], snake_size, snake_size])
    # Apple eating
    if x1 == apple1[0] and y1 == apple1[1]:
        apple_is = False
        snake_list.insert(0, [x1, y1])
        score += 1
    # Draw snake head and body
    if run:
        for x, v in enumerate(snake_list):
            if x == 0:
                pg.draw.rect(win, blue, [int(v[0]), int(v[1]), snake_size, snake_size])
            elif x > 0:
                pg.draw.rect(win, green, [int(v[0]), int(v[1]), snake_size, snake_size])
    font.render_to(win, (board_size[0] + board_margin[1] + board_margin[3], board_margin[0]), f'Score: {score}', white) # score
    font.render_to(win, (board_margin[3], board_size[1] + board_margin[2] + board_margin[0]), f'Press ESC to Exit', white) # escape
    font.render_to(win, (board_margin[3], board_size[1] + board_margin[2] + board_margin[0] + font_size), f'Press P to Pause', white) # pause
    if pause:
        paused_text = font.render_to(win, (2000, 2000), f'Paused', white) # paused message
        font.render_to(win, (board_margin[3] + int(board_size[0]/2) - int(paused_text[2]/2), board_margin[0] + int(board_size[1]/2) - int(paused_text[3]/2)), f'Paused', white)
    
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(speed)
    
pg.quit()
quit()
```

Is this fault of badly written random function? Any ideas how to improve this func?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the function `random_apple` to generate an apple, but not always returning it. A function without a return in python will return `None` by default, so it will store `None` in apple1. In line 124, it is trying to subscript this, presumably to get coordinate values.

`random_apple` needs to always return an apple.

When it delegates to the recursive function, it should return that functions return value. Ie `return random_apple(j)`. Thanks @brunns for that suggestion.

Comment: it is why i did it as a recursive function - shouldn't this resolve this issue?

Comment: You still need to return the value from the recursive call - `return random_apple(j)` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are trying to subscript an object which you think is a list or dict, but actually it is `None`.

In your case, `random_apple` function is returning `None` in some scenario. Default return value of function is `None` in python.

This means that you are trying to do something like this -

```
None[0]
```